# Grouping Elements cannot find in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

i am working with Forge viewer, in Revit file we are creating some elements as groups. when that Revit file uploading in forge viewer  we cannot find any grouping data which given in Revit, we can only saw total element wise groups. is there any way to get the Revit groups into forge viewer?..... please help us to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Except for those two methods advised by Jeremy. There is another way to achieve it by querying viewer property DB.

Currently, Revit groups are not a part of the model structure panel (Instance tree) and don't have a concrete mesh linked to them, so we cannot play with them in the viewer directly, but fortunately they can be found inside the viewer property DB.

Here is a small demo for proving this possibility, please have a try:

```
//
// Copyright (c) Autodesk, Inc. All rights reserved
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in
// object code form for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted,
// provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and
// that both that copyright notice and the limited warranty and
// restricted rights notice below appear in all supporting
// documentation.
//
// AUTODESK PROVIDES THIS PROGRAM "AS IS" AND WITH ALL FAULTS.
// AUTODESK SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY IMPLIED WARRANTY OF
// MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR USE.  AUTODESK, INC.
// DOES NOT WARRANT THAT THE OPERATION OF THE PROGRAM WILL BE
// UNINTERRUPTED OR ERROR FREE.
//
// Forge Autodesk.ADN.RevitGroupPanel
// by Eason Kang - Autodesk Developer Network (ADN)
//

'use strict';

(function() {
  function userFunction( pdb ) {
      let _nameAttrId = pdb.getAttrName();

      let _internalGroupRefAttrId = -1;

      // Iterate over all attributes and find the index to the one we are interested in
      pdb.enumAttributes(function(i, attrDef, attrRaw){

          let category = attrDef.category;
          let name = attrDef.name;

          if( name === 'Group' && category === '__internalref__' ) {
              _internalGroupRefAttrId = i;
              return true; // to stop iterating over the remaining attributes.
          }
      });

      //console.log( _internalGroupRefAttrId );

      // Early return is the model doesn't contain data for "Group".
      if( _internalGroupRefAttrId === -1 )
        return null;

      let _internalMemberRefAttrId = -1;

      // Iterate over all attributes and find the index to the one we are interested in
      pdb.enumAttributes(function(i, attrDef, attrRaw){

          let category = attrDef.category;
          let name = attrDef.name;

          if( name === 'Member' && category === '__internalref__' ) {
              _internalMemberRefAttrId = i;
              return true; // to stop iterating over the remaining attributes.
          }
      });

      //console.log( _internalMemberRefAttrId );

      // Early return is the model doesn't contain data for "Member".
      if( _internalMemberRefAttrId === -1 )
        return null;

      let _categoryAttrId = -1;

      // Iterate over all attributes and find the index to the one we are interested in
      pdb.enumAttributes(function(i, attrDef, attrRaw){

          let category = attrDef.category;
          let name = attrDef.name;

          if( name === 'Category' && category === '__category__' ) {
              _categoryAttrId = i;
              return true; // to stop iterating over the remaining attributes.
          }
      });

      //console.log( _categoryAttrId );

      // Early return is the model doesn't contain data for "Member".
      if( _categoryAttrId === -1 )
        return null;

      const groups = [];
      // Now iterate over all parts to find all groups
      pdb.enumObjects(function( dbId ) {
          let isGroup = false;

          // For each part, iterate over their properties.
          pdb.enumObjectProperties( dbId, function( attrId, valId ) {

              // Only process 'Caegory' property.
              // The word "Property" and "Attribute" are used interchangeably.
              if( attrId === _categoryAttrId ) {
                  const value = pdb.getAttrValue( attrId, valId );
                  if( value === 'Revit Group' ) {
                      isGroup = true;
                      // Stop iterating over additional properties when "Caegory: Revit Group" is found.
                      return true;
                  }
              }
          });

          if( !isGroup ) return;

          const children = [];
          let groupName = '';

          // For each part, iterate over their properties.
          pdb.enumObjectProperties( dbId, function( attrId, valId ) {

              // Only process 'Member' property.
              // The word "Property" and "Attribute" are used interchangeably.
              if( attrId === _internalMemberRefAttrId ) {
                  const value = pdb.getAttrValue( attrId, valId );
                  children.push( value );
              }

              if( attrId === _nameAttrId ) {
                  const value = pdb.getAttrValue( attrId, valId );
                  groupName = value;
              }
          });

          groups.push({
              dbId,
              name: groupName,
              children
          });
      });

      return groups;
  }

  class AdnRevitGroupPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
    constructor( viewer, title, options ) {
      options = options || {};

      //  Height adjustment for scroll container, offset to height of the title bar and footer by default.
      if( !options.heightAdjustment )
        options.heightAdjustment = 70;

      if( !options.marginTop )
        options.marginTop = 0;

      super( viewer.container, viewer.container.id + 'AdnRevitGroupPanel', title, options );

      this.container.classList.add( 'adn-docking-panel' );
      this.container.classList.add( 'adn-rvt-group-panel' );
      this.createScrollContainer( options );

      this.viewer = viewer;
      this.options = options;
      this.uiCreated = false;

      this.addVisibilityListener(( show ) => {
        if( !show ) return;

        if( !this.uiCreated )
          this.createUI();
      });
    }

    async getGroupData() {
      try {
        return await this.viewer.model.getPropertyDb().executeUserFunction( userFunction );
      } catch( ex ) {
        console.error( ex );
        return null;
      }
    }

    async requestContent() {
      const data = await this.getGroupData();
      if( !data ) return;

      for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
        const div = document.createElement( 'div' );
        div.innerText = `${ data[i].name }(${ data[i].children.length })`;
        div.title = `DbId: ${ data[i].dbId }`;
        div.addEventListener(
          'click',
          ( event ) => {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            this.viewer.clearSelection();
            this.viewer.select( data[i].children );
            this.viewer.fitToView( data[i].children );
          });
        this.scrollContainer.appendChild( div );
      }

      this.resizeToContent();
    }

    async createUI() {
      this.uiCreated = true;

      if( this.viewer.model.isLoadDone() ) {
        this.requestContent();
      } else {
        this.viewer.addEventListener(
          Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
          () => this.requestContent(),
          { once: true }
        );
      }
    }
  }

  class AdnRevitGroupPanelExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor( viewer, options ) {
      super( viewer, options );

      this.panel = null;
      this.createUI = this.createUI.bind( this );
      this.onToolbarCreated = this.onToolbarCreated.bind( this );
    }

    onToolbarCreated() {
      this.viewer.removeEventListener(
        Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT,
        this.onToolbarCreated
      );

      this.createUI();
    }

    createUI() {
      const viewer = this.viewer;

      const rvtGroupPanel = new AdnRevitGroupPanel( viewer, 'Revit Group' );

      viewer.addPanel( rvtGroupPanel );
      this.panel = rvtGroupPanel;

      const rvtGroupButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button( 'toolbar-adnRevitGroupTool' );
      rvtGroupButton.setToolTip( 'Revit Group' );
      rvtGroupButton.setIcon( 'adsk-icon-properties' );
      rvtGroupButton.onClick = function() {
        rvtGroupPanel.setVisible( !rvtGroupPanel.isVisible() );
      };

      const subToolbar = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup( 'toolbar-adn-tools' );
      subToolbar.addControl( rvtGroupButton );
      subToolbar.adnRvtGroupButton = rvtGroupButton;
      this.subToolbar = subToolbar;

      viewer.toolbar.addControl( this.subToolbar );

      rvtGroupPanel.addVisibilityListener(function( visible ) {
        if( visible )
          viewer.onPanelVisible( rvtGroupPanel, viewer );

          rvtGroupButton.setState( visible ? Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button.State.ACTIVE : Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button.State.INACTIVE );
      });
    }

    load() {
      if( this.viewer.toolbar ) {
        // Toolbar is already available, create the UI
        this.createUI();
      } else {
        // Toolbar hasn't been created yet, wait until we get notification of its creation
        this.viewer.addEventListener(
          Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT,
          this.onToolbarCreated
        );
      }

      return true;
    }

    unload() {
      if( this.panel ) {
        this.panel.uninitialize();
        delete this.panel;
        this.panel = null;
      }

      if( this.subToolbar ) {
        this.viewer.toolbar.removeControl( this.subToolbar );
        delete this.subToolbar;
        this.subToolbar = null;
      }

      return true;
    }
  }

  Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension( 'Autodesk.ADN.RevitGroupPanel', AdnRevitGroupPanelExtension );
})();

viewer.loadExtension( 'Autodesk.ADN.RevitGroupPanel' );
```

Here is the snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you certainly know, Forge is a fully generic CAD modelling environment.

Therefore, it mainly provides support for cross-domain CAD functionality.

The Revit grouping functionality that you seek is BIM specific and cannot be recreated in a useful manner for all domains in Forge.

There are numerous way that you can work around this.

Here are two main approaches you might want to consider:

- Implement a Revit add-in to retrieve and export the grouping data and make it available to your Forge app
- Implement an app in Forge Design Automation for Revit to gather the required data from the RVT hosted in Forge